# How can I query TEntity based on property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this query to dbset based on passed id

```
public TEntity Get(int id)
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
}
```

Then I realized that sometimes I need to eagerload its properties so I added an overload

```
public TEntity Get(int id, string includeProperties)
{

    IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
    (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return query.Single(i => i.) //I don't know this part here
}
```

I wanted to do `return query.Single(i => i.Id == id)` but it doesn't work.

In `i.Id` it says

> "TEntity does not contain a definition of Id" since it's a generic entity.

Comment: consider using an Expression then for the provided parameter.

Comment: can you shed me an idea on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
   protected readonly YourDbContext _context;
   public Repository(YourDbContext DbContextScope)  //Intitalizing DBContext
   {
     if(DbContextScope == null)
     {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("DbContextScope");
     }
     _context = DbContextScope.Create();
   }
 public TEntity FindSingleEager(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, List<string> paths)
 {
     var query = _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
     foreach (string path in paths)
     {
       query = query.Include(path);
     }
     return query.SingleOrDefault<TEntity>();
  }
}
```

You can call it this way

```
var yourRepository  = new YourRepository(YourDbcontextScope);
var res = yourRepository
          .FindSingleEager(i => i.Id == id , new List<string>() { "Path1","Path2" ,"Path3"});
```

> You can modify repository to create your dbcontext instead of creating it by passing instance , it's your choice.